# How to load a TSV containing an Array JSON field in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to load a file with a schema that is primarily tab separated values, but one of the fields is an ARRAY JSON value.

Each row of the data look like:

```
date\tuser_id\tproducts
```

products field is an Array Json formatted string.

What is the easiest way to load this data ?

Comment: Array Json has fixed no of elements or not ?? Means no of elements in array JSON has fixed or not ???

Comment: @AnkurSingh This Array Json has not fixed number of elements

Answer (score 0):

One way is to load the TSV file with standard load command and write UDF to parse the json